# Spacemacs issues since upgrading to v.0.2.00.5

Tags: spacemacs

I’ve had some issues with Spacemacs since upgrading. I don’t know if these are genuine bugs or if it’s in my configuration. I’m using Windows 7 and my version of emacs 25.0.92.1
1. I get the following warnings on start up:

```
- Unknown layer unimpaired declared in dotfile.
- tern binary not found!
```

[**edit**: To fix turn follow these instructions - https://simpletutorials.com/c/2784/How+to+setup+JavaScript+auto-complete+in+Spacemacs+on+Windows]

2. Space Space gives the message: `SPC SPC undefined`
   I thought it had changed from `evil-avy-goto-word` to `M-x`

[**edit**: My .spacemacs was at fault. I was using a version pre version 2. Reinstalling fixed this]

3. When using a search engine I added (SPC a / Search engine select) I get an error: `wrong type argument: commandp, engine/search-mySearch`, though this worked before the upgrade.
   This is how my search is configured -

   ```
   ;;Search Engines
   (push '(mySearch
         :name "mySearch"
         :url "http://mySearch/%s")
         search-engine-alist)
   ```

Are these genuine bugs or is there something I need to correct?